# Where is the db value defined for Play Slick?

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I'm trying to define a query using Slick in Play to search for a row by id. I am trying to understand how this all works, so I can actually develop this thing, and not just blindly write whatever I find online. This led me to want to find what the 'db' object in all of these examples is.

```
class UserDao @Inject()(protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] {
    import driver.api._

    private class UsersTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "users") {
        def id = column[Int]("id", O.AutoInc, O.PrimaryKey)
        def name = column[String]("name")
        def age = column[Int]("age")
        def email = column[String]("email")

        def * = (name, age, email) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply _)
    }

    private val Users = TableQuery[UsersTable]

    def all: Future[Seq[User]] = db.run(Users.result)

    def insert(user: User): Future[Unit] = db.run(Users += user).map { _ => () }

    def read(id: Int): Future[User] = db.run(for (user <- Users; if user.id === id) yield user)

}
```

Where is the value 'db' from the 'db.run(...)' come from? I found this line in the DatabaseConfigProvider source, but I don't understand it.

```
protected final def db: P#Backend#Database = dbConfig.db
```

That dbConfig is a DatabaseConfig object, but the docs don't show a 'db' value member on that object.

I am using a PostgreSQL database in case that makes any difference. I don't think it does, but I'll add that detail for completeness.

I'm just not sure where this is coming from, could someone please explain it?

Comment: It comes from Slick itself, see [here](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/api/index.html#slick.backend.DatabaseConfig). I don't understand it myself very well, but it represents one database, since you can use multiple databases in your app.

Comment: Hmm, I was looking at the docs, but couldn't see the 'db' member value. I must have been looking at an older version of the docs. Thanks